# what is compatable version of spring-kafka for spring framwork 2.1.0

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-framework-beans

Tried to run an example of  spring framwork version 2.1.0 and spring.core 3.2.5. The type org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture cannot be resolved is error while importing kafka template.please suggest the compatable version of spring-kafka

Comment: Please, just start from Spring Boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ and don't care about dependencies versions. It is indeed that there is already nothing compatible with Spring Framework 3.2.5. That's too old and out of support version already.

Comment: thank u for response.i have another issue, suggest which version is compatable for spring.core of version 3.2.5 for non spring-boot project

Comment: I said already: there is no such a compatibility. The Spring for Apache Kafka has been started much later, than that Spring version went in vain